# Function array not pulling back all rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I currently have a table called category in my database

### category

#### catId categoy

1. News
2. HTML
3. PHP
4. CSS

Trying to pull back off rows from the database only brings back the 1 result using the following code

```
    private function navigation(){
        $url = BASE_URL;
        $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if (!$dbc) {
            trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL:' .mysqli_error());
        }
    $query = "SELECT catId, category AS 'catName' FROM category ORDER BY catName DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br>MySQL Error: ");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $name = $row['catName'];
            $catId = $row['catId'];
            $this -> nav =<<<NAVIGATION
            <li>$name</li>
            <p>test</p>

NAVIGATION;
       }
    }
```

I have tried doing it outside a function and all rows are brought back without problem.

```
$querying = "SELECT catId, category AS 'catName' FROM category ORDER BY catName ASC";
        $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $querying) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br>MySQL Error: ");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
            $name = $row['catName'];
            $catId = $row['catId'];

            $page->body ("$name");
        }
```

I was wondering if someone could guide me in where I am going wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you expecting multiple results? `$this->nav` and `$page->body` is overwritten on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

On first code you everytime assign value to `$this -> nav` variable so it gives you last data from the array of mysql result.
 And its not true use database connect everytime when you call function.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you want to append each row to the previous rows.  Try

`$this -> nav .=` ...

(dot equals)